# Mod Rewrite "Exceeded limit of 10 redirects"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I have a redirect rule written like so:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /public-profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

This is meant to change, for example:

```
http://www.domain.com/public-profile.php?name=username
```

To:

```
http://www.domain.com/username
```

For some reason, it is creating an infinite loop, as I am getting a 500 internal server error if you go to the site, and it says this in Apache's error.log:

Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.   Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.

Based on my research, this means that the rewrite rule is creating an infinite loop. Any ideas, Internet people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the following?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public-profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```